# Adding a Python script to Application Launcher

Tags: gnome-panel, python

I'm using Gnome 2.32.0 in Ubuntu 10.10 and I need to execute a Python script via Gnome custom application launcher. I added an application launcher to the panel and pointed the relevant Python script, but every time I try to run it, I get an error message along these lines:

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal
Failed to execute child process "/home/dananjaya/xkcd_viewer/xkcd_gui.py" (Permission denied)
```

What is the correct way of adding a Python script to the application launcher? What is wrong in this case? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't have permissions to execute the script. There are two possible solutions:

1. Prefix the command with python,
   e. g. `python /path/to/myscript.py`
   instead of `/path/to/myscript.py`.
   That way, the python interpreter
   will read your script instead of the
   executed script calling the python
   interpreter, and the permissions on
   the script may stay the same.
2. Enable execution-permissions for
       the script. Right-click the script
       in the file manager, choose
       properties and tick the execution
       permission under the permissions
       tab. This solution implies that your script can be identified by the shell as a python-script. To do this, you must place `#!/usr/bin/env python` on the first line of the file.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions and I tried both of them. I enabled the execution-permission. also did prefix the command with 'python'. Now it doesn't give the aforementioned error but does nothing at all. I looked at all the processes running and the script does not run.

Comment: It sound like you have other bugs. It might be caused by the script running with another working directory instead of its main directory. Try running the exact same command as the launcher in a terminal and see if you get any exceptions.

Comment: No exceptions occur. Script runs okay in the terminal.

Comment: If you preface the command with `gnome-terminal -e`, the script will run from a terminal (which will die as soon as it completes).

Comment: I have this as the command, "gnome-terminal -e  /home/dananjaya/xkcd_viewer/xkcd_gui.py" Now it just starts a terminal window, and mouse pointer in to a cross-hair and does nothing. whenever I click outside the terminal window, it closes..

Comment: Also adding 'python' in front of the path, just starts the python interpreter.

Comment: Does your script rely on any changed variables such as `PATH`, `PYTHONPATH` etc that might be set in your shell but not in X?

Comment: Well, there is none as I see. Anyway if it helps, here's the script at github. (Sorry for not putting it in the question, it has 2 source files and bit large for that) https://github.com/dananjayavr/xkcd_viewer

Comment: I cloned your repository and got `gnome-terminal -e "python /home/egil/src/xkcd_viewer/xkcd_gui.py"` to work as launcher. However, I cannot understand why executing the script directly yields a cross-hair.

Comment: Thanks for going in to much trouble to answer my question. Me too got it working now. Anyway the cross-hair thing maybe a bug?

Comment: Of course, you lack the shebang at the start of your script. The first line should read `#!/usr/bin/env python`. The crosshair comes from the `import` command that gets executed because your script gets read as a batch of commands as it lacks the shebang that explains that it must be executed with python.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot for your help egil. I overlooked something very important. :-)